# Adding a red horizontal line to my plot

Tags: plotting

I have a list of numbers which I have named "result" and which I modify according to certain rules. At the end of the routine, I plot the list with the command:

> ListPlot[result, PlotRange -> Automatic]

I would like to add the horizontal line y=1 (in red) to my plot. Is there a simple way to modify the previous command in order to attain such an effect?

Thanks a bunch for your insightful replies!

Comment: Try `InfiniteLine` as a `Prolog`.

Comment: Look up `Gridlines`

Comment: @Alan: Would you be so kind as to elaborate?

Comment: I tried "ListPlot[result, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
 Prolog -> {Red, InfiniteLine[{0, 1}, {2, 1}]}]", but I am not getting the desired effect

Comment: `ListPlot[RandomReal[2, {100, 2}], PlotRange -> Automatic, 
 Prolog -> {Red, InfiniteLine[{0, 1}, {1000, 1}]}]`

Answer (score 4):

I also believe `GridLines` is easier

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[2, {100, 2}], GridLines -> {None, {1}}, GridLinesStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

An issue with both InfiniteLine and Gridlines is that the inserted line can significantly overshoot the vertical axis:

[image]

There may be a way to correct this [EDIT: There is—see Carl Woll's comment below]; but to avoid having to bother, you could use Show to combine your plot with another plot of y = 1:

```
Show[ListPlot[RandomReal[2, {100, 2}]], Plot[1, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: The `GridLines` extend over the whole plot range, which due to the `PlotRangePadding->Automatic` default setting extends to about -.05. Use `PlotRangePadding->0` to avoid this.